# What are the strengths of the IAsyncResult pattern?

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-2.0, iasyncresult

I feel that many classes (e.g. `TcpClient`, `UdpClient`, `HttpListener`) would've been much easier to understand and use if they were event driven. And `IAsyncResult` pattern is excessively hard to implement because it opens you to all kinds of weird use cases:

1. What if caller calls multiple Begin methods in a row?
2. What if caller mixes Begin and regular methods?

And so on. Nevertheless, Microsoft has chosen to use it in most places. Why?

**Edit:** Please focus the discussion on .NET 2.0 as that's what I have to work with.

Comment: [MSDN: Interop with Other Asynchronous Patterns and Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> And so on. Nevertheless, Microsoft has chosen to use it in most places. Why?

The async pattern using `IAsyncResult` was the original asynchronous programming pattern used within the Framework.  It has few advantages, and the complexity has led to new patterns being developed over time.

Event Asynchronous Programming (EAP) was introduced later (where you have a "Begin" method with a completion event).  This solved a lot of the complexity, but was still difficult to use in many situations, as you have to split your logic into multiple methods still.

However, the current asynchronous pattern is based around .NET 4's `Task` and `Task<T>` class, and provides huge advantages, especially when coupled with C# 5's async/await support.  Luckily, [TaskFactory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) can be used to easily wrap an `IAsyncResult` based asynchronous method pair into a `Task<T>` automatically, so the new patterns can be used.  .NET 4.5 has added new versions of many of the framework's asynchronous methods which return `Task<T>`, so the new `async`/`await` language support can be used with the framework methods.  This is the preferred method moving forward for all asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 4):

This pattern doesn't have many strengths.

In .Net 1.0, before generics and lambda expressions, this was the only asynchronous pattern available.

The more modern task-based pattern is much nicer for a number of reasons, including type-safety, simpler error handling, continuations, `When*()` methods, and others.