# Invoke, BeginInvoke / EndInvoke or InvokeAsync? what to use when and why?

Tags: c#, vb.net, powershell

In reference to using PowerShell in VB or C# via System.Management.Automation

I know that Invoke runs synchronously, and using BeginInvoke / EndInvoke means you can do same thing asynchronously.

But I noticed today that there is also InvokeAsync

Can anyone explain to me the benefit of using this over the other methods and if there is a particular method I should be using?

Most examples I see use Invoke for basic commands and BeginInvoke / EndInvoke for longer running tasks.

Just want to learn best approach and have an understanding of what to use when as can't find much documentation on InvokeAsync like I could the others.

update: Quick examples below of same code using Invoke or BeginInvoke/EndInvoke

Thanks

```
    Dim powershell As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
    powershell.AddCommand("Get-Process")

    Dim results = powershell.BeginInvoke

   Do While results.IsCompleted = False

            ' wait whilst command completes

    Loop


    For Each result As PSObject In powershell.EndInvoke(results)

      UpdateTextBox("Process Name: " & result.Members("ProcessName").Value & " Process ID: " & result.Members("Id").Value & vbCrLf)

    Next result
```

or

```
   Dim powershell As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
    powershell.AddCommand("Get-Process")

    Dim results = powershell.Invoke


    For Each result As PSObject In results

        UpdateTextBox("Process Name: " & result.Members("ProcessName").Value & " Process ID: " & result.Members("Id").Value & vbCrLf)

    Next result
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the strengths of the IAsyncResult pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750532/what-are-the-strengths-of-the-iasyncresult-pattern)

Comment: If you are using the Tasks Parallel Library and `async`/`await` in the rest of your code then you should use `InvokeAsync`, which returns a `Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>>`. If you're not using async code via the TPL elsewhere then don't do it here either.

Comment: Added example of some basic code used above, this can be used with the three methods I mentioned. I am not using TPL

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the TPL throughout your app then use `InvokeAsync`. You can await the call or not, just as you can for any other async method.

If you need an invocation to be synchronous, e.g. your background operation has to wait to get input from the UI, then use `Invoke`.

If you don't need an invocation to be synchronous then use `BeginInvoke`. If you need to get data back then use `EndInvoke` as well. For instance, if you are performing an operation in the background and updating a `ProgressBar`, you should call `BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke`. That's because there's no need for the background work to wait while the that update happens. You don't need any result though, so there's no need to call `EndInvoke`.